# Chunk Upload Faster on Local Host

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a chunk upload js script I found in another post on here. When I run it on local host, it's fast. But when I run it on my live url, there's about 20 seconds of Request Sent under Chrome's Network Panel for timing. The Request Sent isn't running on localhost. I'm worried it's sending the complete file in the first chunk instead of just 1 MB.

Is there a different security measure for uploads, like is chrome running a virus scan? Is there any way I can confirm?

```
const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunk sizes.
var slices;
var slices2;

function sendRequest() {
    var xhr;
    var blob = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0];
    var start = 0;
    var end;
    var index = 0;
    responseCount=0;
    // calculate the number of slices we will need
    slices = Math.ceil(blob.size / BYTES_PER_CHUNK);
    slices2 = slices;

    while(start < blob.size) {
        end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        if(end > blob.size) {
            end = blob.size;
        }

        uploadFile(blob, index, start, end);

        start = end;
        index++;
    }
}

function uploadFile(blob, index, start, end) {
    var xhr;
    var end;
    var fd;
    var chunk;
    var url;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if(xhr.responseText) {
                responseCount++;
                jQuery('#uploadMessage').text("Uploading Progress: "+Math.ceil((responseCount/slices2)*100)+"%");                
            }

            slices--;

            // if we have finished all slices
            if(slices == 0) {
                mergeFile(blob);
            }
        }
    };

    if (blob.webkitSlice) {
        chunk = blob.webkitSlice(start, end);
    } else if (blob.mozSlice) {
        chunk = blob.mozSlice(start, end);
    }
    chunk = blob.slice(start, end);

    fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", chunk);
    fd.append("name", blob.name);
    fd.append("index", index);

    xhr.open("POST", "/index.php?chunkupload=upload", true);
    xhr.send(fd);
}

function mergeFile(blob) {
    jQuery('#uploadMessage').text("Closing Upload");
    var xhr;
    var fd;

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("name", blob.name);
    fd.append("index", slices2);
    fd.append("userinputname",jQuery('#userinputname').val());
    fd.append("userinputdescr",jQuery('#userinputdescr').val());

    xhr.open("POST", "/index.php?chunkmerge=upload", true);
    xhr.send(fd);
    jQuery('#uploadMessage').text("Upload Complete. Video will be published upon site approval.");
}
```

Comment: re: "I'm worried it's sending the complete file in the first chunk", use the network tab to see what was uploaded, no need to worry or guess. also, i wouldn't be surprised  if some remote hosts take 20 seconds to catch a meg...

Comment: Yes you are right. I saw it under Content-Length in the Request headers.